# How to make Generic of list variable Serializable

Tags: java, list, generics, serializable, transient

How can I make `private List <T> list;` or `private Map<String, Value> unknownData;` **serializable**? These are variable in my class whose parent is serializable but SonarQube is complaining about transient or Serializable change

**myClass.java**

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
  protected  List<T>  list = new ArrayList<T>();
```

[image: Screen shot of SonarQube complaint]

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of what SonarQube is showing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the class(es) declaration(s), extend the types with `Serializable`.

For example :

```
public class MyClass<T extends Serializable>{ ...
```

and

```
public class MyOtherClass<Value extends Serializable>{ ...
```

Comment: I think, SonarQube is complaining about `List<..>` not being serializable, `<T>` is not the problem ... `List<..>` has to be serializable (e.g. `ArrayList`), but on the other hand the field should be rather the most general suitable (so `List<..>` is recommended) - in the end, serializability is needed at runtime - it's not necessary to have a fixed type of `List` that's serializable.